# Repo, gerrit & Jenkins co-working

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, repo, gerrit-trigger

I have a problem with getting Google's Repo, gerrit & Jenkins working together.

**our setup:**

we have a Repo build out of few git repositories, which are all on our gerrit server. Manifest is also there.

**Workflow:**

- user do changes in few files which sits in different git repositories in the Rep.
- user commit & push the changes to Code review.

**Problem:**

- for each of the repositories, a separate gerrit code review is created.
- For each of those code reviews, Jenkins is being triggered.

If the changes are inter-depended (which they usually do), the Jenkins build will fail, as it takes only the changes in one repository each time.

How do we make Jenkins/Gerrit co-op to get the full changes into one build (that will work)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The configuration described here is very problematic,
and is sure to cause you grief in the future as well.

In the long run, consider one of those paths:

- Reduce dependency between the components to the minimum
  (this is preferred)
- Merge the code to a single repository

Meanwhile -

- Make sure the verification-job (in Jenkins) *checks-out the latest code from all the other repositories*
  (those that are relevant for building this change)
- Make (non-breaking) changes to one repository at a time
  (requires some planning, of course)